# Is serializable inheritable

Tags: java, serialization

Is serializable inheritable. Particulary if I have

```
class A implements Serializable{}

class B extends A{}
```

Is class B serializable?

Comment: `B` isn't serializable it inherits from super class implements the `Serializable` interface, IMO that semantics matter in Java.

Comment: This is clearly mentioned in the Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), "*Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. **All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.***"

Comment: @0x90: Extending a class or implementing an interface precisely defines an *is a* relationship. So yes, B *is a* Serializable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This follows from the concept of inheritance in Java. Since A is serializable and B extends A, B is serializalbe.

Note that all non-static non-transient fields of A and B must also contain Serializable objects, otherwise there will be a NotSerializableException at runtime when you try to serialize them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  subclass of a Serializable class is also serializable

For more information

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/

Comment: The only reference required is the [JLS #8.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5). Nothing to do specifically with `Serializable` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Did the following check on given code

```
boolean b = new B() instanceof Serializable;
System.out.println(b);
```

which returns `true`

Comment: It isn't necessary to execute code to answer this question. It concerns a property of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @EJP ohk!! but wanted answer some other different way. If not making sense i will delete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the super class implements [serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), then so do the sub classes.

Answer (score 0):

If a class is Serializable then all subclasses are Serializable. But if you want to prevent sub class whose superclass is Serializable to be serializable it is also possible.

If you want to prevent then use

**NotSerializableException** -- Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface. The serialization runtime or the class of the instance can throw this exception. The argument should be the name of the class.

**Refer official docs** -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html

By using it in this way you can accomplish this task

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {

    throw new NotSerializableException(“Not today!”);
}


private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in ) throws IOException {

    throw new NotSerializableException(“Not today!”);

}
```

**How about sub class is serialized But parent class is not**

If a Sub class is Serializable, it absolutely does not mean that its super class is also Serializable. When a subclass is de - serialized, the no-argument Constructor of the super class will run.

Answer (score 0):

[oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html):

> Interfaces have another very important role in the Java programming
>   language. Interfaces are not part of the class hierarchy, although
>   they work in combination with classes. The Java programming language
>   does not permit multiple inheritance (inheritance is discussed later
>   in this lesson), but interfaces provide an alternative.
>
> In Java, a class can inherit from only one class but it can implement
>   more than one interface. Therefore, objects can have multiple types:
>   the type of their own class and the types of all the interfaces that
>   they implement. This means that if a variable is declared to be the
>   type of an interface, its value can reference any object that is
>   instantiated from any class that implements the interface. This is
>   discussed later in this lesson, in the section titled "Using an
>   Interface as a Type."

I guess what you mean Is if you have a function `foo` which gets `(Serializable ptr)`, can you call it with an instance of `Class B` so the answer is yes, that is the Idea.

moreover you can Override the the A (ancestor) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

*All* interfaces implemented by base classes are inherited by their derived classes. Not just Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Serializable-ness is inherited, but have had problems (albeit rarely) where that fact is not recognized by the occasional tool.  So even though it's not required, I will make the extra effort to also declare the subclass as implementing Serializable.